# Как передать несколько объектов в представление?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Как передать несколько объектов в представление??

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {

        return View(new LoginViewModel());
    }
```

Видел вариант где несколько объектов помещаются в один специально созданный для него, какие еще есть варианты??

Comment: использовать `ViewBag`

Comment: Или ViewModel [ссылка](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11064316/what-is-viewmodel-in-mvc)